# Is $a+b$ a unit if $a,b,a-b$ are zero divisors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ such that each element is either a unit or a zero divisor. 
Let $a,b,a-b$ be zero divisors. Can $a+b$ be a unit or must it already be a zero divisor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try $a=2$, $b=5$ in $\mathbb Z/30\mathbb Z$.

From [computational evidence](https://pastebin.com/c50Vn6Dm), it seems that the $n$ for which we can find $a$ and $b$ with $a$, $b$, $a-b$ zero divisors and $a+b$ a unit in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ are exactly the $n$ that are divisible by at least three different primes. See [oeis.org/A000977](https://oeis.org/A000977). I'd love to [see a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2805372/ring-of-integers-modulo-n-with-a-property-for-the-zero-divisors).

Empirically, the smallest prime divisor of $n$ works for $a$, but the next prime divisor of $n$ does not always work for $b$.

Comment: Beat me to it by ten seconds or so. Three prime factors.

Comment: thank you for your answer

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I wrote a program. Did you see it at once? If so, please tell us how.

Comment: Btw, is there a nice example of "either unit or zero-divisor" that is not of the form $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42647/rings-in-which-every-non-unit-is-a-zero-divisor. The [dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) are an example.

Comment: Not at once. First I wanted comment that this is true in $\Bbb{Z}_{2^m}$ and the like. Then I did a quick check that moving to $\Bbb{Z}_6$ didn't help. Then I observed that if $m$ has three prime factors then it can be done. But your post showed up just when I came up with an example. Mine was $a=8, b=5$ :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Maybe you have an idea for the general case? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2805372/ring-of-integers-modulo-n-with-a-property-for-the-zero-divisors